# Upload one image with multiple sizes in wordpress programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload

thanks in advance
I am finding a solution, that how can I upload an image with 3 more image sizes in WordPress frontend, am currently using wp media to upload images  but it upload's one by one

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this? What's the case?

You can upload a big one and then get different sizes programmatically or via a media gallery.

Try to use
`wp_get_attachment_image()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Comment: thanks, serhii but i need to upload 3 different attachments